# Nonlinear Least Squares Parameter Optimisation Constrain as param1<param2<param3<param4

Tags: python, scipy, nonlinear-optimization, scipy-optimize

I am trying to develop a battery model and now estimating parameters to my model according to test. data.

`from scipy.optimize import least_squares` I use nonlinear least squares. I have OCV(Open Circuit Voltage) curve as a lookup table related to SOC(State of Charge from 0 to 1.0).

I am trying to optimise OCV curve so treat it as 201 parameters. Because of the battery nature OCV[k-1] <= OCV[k] so cuz battery voltages goes down or up during charge and discharge. But as you can see from the figure(see the link) optimisation doesn't care about it. Some ripples happens. Actually before I was using simulink and it was not happening.

I can put bounds but I want to put constrain as OCV[k] >= OCV[k-1] during optimisation. Is there any way to do that with least squares or scipy or any other lib or language?

Thanks in advance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc7Wi.png

Comment: Could you provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: One obvious way: implement this explicitly as constraints. So use a solver that can handle constraints. Scipy has a few.

Comment: Hi Joni! Here you can use the first example. I implemented my code from here also. https://hernandis.me/2020/04/05/three-examples-of-nonlinear-least-squares-fitting-in-python-with-scipy.html